# Visual Studio Team Services: What permissions are needed to create team projects?

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS (aka Visual Studio Online, aka Visual Studio Team Services), I'd like to be able to have people other than collection administrators create team projects, but I can't figure out what permissions I need to grant to the VSTS group I created for that purpose.  I set "Create new projects" to allow, but users in that group are still unable to create new projects.  I've confirmed there are no groups that have 'deny' set for the 'create new projects' permission, but it still doesn't work.

Is there an additional permission I need to grant to that group to let it's members create projects?

Comment: "Create new projects" permission should be enough. Can you share a screenshot for the security settings? And can you also set the permission to allow for a specific user and check if it can works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user cannot be specified Stakeholder access level, change to Basic and try again.

1. Go to Users page http://[account].visualstudio.com/_user
2. Select the user
3. Click Edit
4. Change Access Level to basic
5. Click Save

More information, you can refer to this article: [Manage users and access in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services)

Comment: The user I tried it with has a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription associated with them, so they're not a stakeholder.

Comment: @JonathanRupp What's the detail error message you get? What's the result with other user that just has Basic access level?

Comment: Turns out, this users with a VS enterprise subscription has been moving it back and forth to a client's account and currently has a "VS1720077: Subscription could not be validated" error.  Tried it with someone who's using their account properly, and it works just fine.