# Visual Studio Team Services: Is there a way to grant global read permissions?

Tags: azure-devops

I've been through all the permissions you can grant to groups at the collection level (`https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_security`), but don't see any permission that looks like it'd control the ability to read/admin all the projects in the collection.  I don't even see any inheritance that's giving the "Project Collection Administrators" group admin rights over the projects, which is making me afraid that it's just 'magic' that I can't customize.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Expected this to be a snap once I figured out how to [let non-admins create projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031610) (yeah, it's really that easy).  I've got to be missing something here.

Comment: If you are hitting this problem you likely have too many Team Projects. Most people spend there time in one Team Project: https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/

Comment: My aim here isn't to grant lots of people this "read all projects" permission - I want to give it to like 10 people in a company of 500 who have responsibilities to 'drop in' on other projects to see what's going on.

Comment: I don't think single-project is the solution for our scenario - we don't have people moving between projects that frequently - they're usually focused on one (or a few) at a time.  Also, since we're doing work for clients, our projects tend to be relatively short-lived (order of months) and include outside users who can't be allowed to see the other projects.

Comment: Use an AD group and add it to the readers or contributers group for each team project.

Answer (score 0):

No, read/admin permission can’t be granted globally for all projects. You should set permissions for different projects separately.

For a project security setting (https://account.visualstudio.com/projectname/_admin/_security), you can add users who’s permission is read in reader group.

Answer (score 0):

As with most systems if you find something hard then you are probably using it wrong.

https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/

The majority of your users should be spending the majority of their time in a single Team Project. The Team Project boundary isna hard one to cross and flipping between team projects is a pain. Fpr most organisation and most product teams one Team Project is all you need.

I need way more info to be sure, but your question implies to me that you have a whole bunch of team projects that the sake group of users need access to. This makes it a pain to manage security and you want to create server level groups to manage this. Now while the Product Team are working hard to address things like this it will take time to make the underlying changes that would enable it.

In the mean time you should look to merge all of your Team Projects into one (or logical groups based on people/product/assets that allow users to access as few team projects as posible.

As an example the Office, Windows, Xbox, and VSTS teams at Microsoft's all have one team project each. Even though they have multiple projects, teams, and products under each.

As a rule of thumb: If you have assets that interact then they should all be in one team project. I defign assets as people, code, or work items.